# How to pass in multiple parameters as entity on xsodata call?

Tags: odata, sapui5, hana-xs

```
var dataURL = "urlTo .xsodata file";

var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(dataURL, true);
var products = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();

oModel.read("/input('"+input+"')/Results/", null, null, true, function(oData){
products.setData(oData.results);
});

this.getView.setModel(products);
```

This is my .xsodata file

```
service napespace "_SYS_BIC"{
"calc View Name" as "PricingTool"
parameters via entity "input"
results property "Results";
}
```

I tried adding more entities with different names and calling those when I make the OData call but that didn't work. How can I update this to allow more parameters?

Comment: How do you add more entities? Are you using Batch-Processing?

Comment: no I'm not. The the calc view takes different inputs, some being strings and some being integers. I thought that doing multiple lines like "parameters via entity "input" would work but that's clearly wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass multiple parameters in an XSOData call by exposing parameters in the service declaration & then passing them in the service URL.

**XSODATA**

```
service 
{
    "viewpath/ViewName.calculationview"  as "PricingTool" 
    keys generate local "GENERATED_ID" 
    parameters via entity "PricingTool_InputParams" results property "Execute"
}
```

**URL**

```
/PricingTool_InputParams(ip_field1='A',ip_field2='B',ip_field3='C')/Execute
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. I had to to have someone else help me out with this, but this is the correct way to do it.

Comment: If it is the correct answer, can you please mark it as correct